# How to link armory wallet with Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, armory

I have a new PC and have downloaded Bitcoin Core v 25.  I have 'restored' my Armory wallet on new PC but cannot get them to link up?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your Bitcoin core fully synchronised?